# How can I give Web API access to a certain domain/url?

Tags: c#, api

I want to expose my Web API to only certain domain.Right now it is public and accessible to everyone. So how could I stop it and make it secure and accessible to particular consumer?

Comment: Hi And welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please add more details? Did you enable CORS for all domains, do you want to add authentication/authorization or something else?

Comment: Please add more details about your API and how it is deployed to avoid a drawn-out discussion in the comments. There are various ways to accomplish your goal, but details matter.

Answer (score 2):

Please implement CORS in your WEB API.

For more details you can visit below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api
https://dzone.com/articles/access-control-allow-origin-header-and-the-aspnet